# Dynamic ASHX Data Viewed In amCharts

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts, ashx

I am working with a .ashx data handler that successfully calls and returns a valid JSON formatting (confirmed using http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html).

I want to use that returned data in a amChart. My chart works correctly with hardcoded data. How do I make the chart accept the dynamic ashx JSON data?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        "type": "serial",
        "theme": "light",
        "marginRight": 70,
        "dataProvider": [{
            "date": "11/04/2014",
            "val1": 125,
            "val2": 150
         }, {
            "date": "11/05/2014",
            "val1": 100,
            "val2": 130
         }, 
         // ETC
         ]
         "valueAxes": [{
             "axisAlpha": 0,
             "position": "left",
             "title": "Visitors By Date"
         }],
        "graphs": [{
            "id": "val1",
            "title": "val1bar",
            "valueField": "val1",
            "type": "column",
            "balloonText": "VAL1<br>[[date]]<br>[[val1]]</div>"
        }, {
            "id": "val2",
            "title": "val2bar",
            "valueField": "val2",
            "type": "column",
            "balloonText": "VAL1<br>[[date]]<br>[[val1]]</div>"
        }],       
        "chartCursor": {
            "pan": true,
            "valueLineEnabled": true,
            "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
            "cursorAlpha": 0,
            "valueLineAlpha": 0.2
        },
        "categoryField": "date",
        "categoryAxis": {
            "gridPosition": "start",
            "labelRotation": 45
        },
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way for you to utilize JSON output from the ASHX is amChart's own [Data Loader](http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/using-data-loader-plugin/) plugin.

Basically you would just need to include `amcharts/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js`, then replace `dataProvider` with `dataLoader` info, like this:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "marginRight": 70,
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "mydata.ashx"
  },
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Visitors By Date"
  } ],
  "graphs": [ {
    "id": "val1",
    "title": "val1bar",
    "valueField": "val1",
    "type": "column",
    "balloonText": "VAL1<br>[[date]]<br>[[val1]]</div>"
  }, {
    "id": "val2",
    "title": "val2bar",
    "valueField": "val2",
    "type": "column",
    "balloonText": "VAL1<br>[[date]]<br>[[val1]]</div>"
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "pan": true,
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "valueLineAlpha": 0.2
  },
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "labelRotation": 45
  },
} );
```

Data Loader expects JSON data by default, so you don't need to set any other options.

Comment: You were correct. Thank you.

To append your solution, I also needed to do a postProcess because I was using a sub array in my JSON

"dataLoader": {
            "url": "queries/dataHandler_getDailyIncidentCount.ashx",
                "postProcess": function(jsonData) {
                    return jsonData.aaData;
                },
            "format": "json"
        },